# Why PostgreSQL is forcing me to use just one primary key on a cross-table?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm trying to save an object with hibernate using one to many relationship and PostgreSQL is forcing me to have just one primary key on a cross-table. The thing I want to do is to make a cross table have 2 primary keys together. So I can avoid the duplicate foreign key exception.

I have been searching for while on how to overcome this but i can't get it right. Is this something that PostgreSQL do by default? or do i have to use MySQL?

Any tips on why this is happening?

*Note: Also if I insert on the cross-table one set of "Tratamiento" different every time, it works fine. The problem comes when I'm trying to save a Tratamiento that was stored before but with a different Cita, in theory that's good because of the 2 columns being primary key, it doesn't mean a problem. But since PostgreSQL is forcing the cross-table to have just a one primary key, that's when the problem comes.

Here is the class I'm trying to save:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CITA", schema = "COLINASCO")
public class Cita implements Serializable{
    private long id;
    private Date fecha;
    private Time hora;
    private Paciente paciente;
    private Empleado empleado;
    private Set<Tratamiento> listaTratamientos;

    public Cita() {
        fecha = null;
        hora = null;
        paciente = null;
        empleado = null;
        listaTratamientos = null;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CITA_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "FECHA", nullable = false)
    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    @Column(name = "HORA", nullable = false)
    public Time getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(Time hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PACIENTE_ID")
    public Paciente getPaciente() {
        return paciente;
    }

    public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLEADO_ID")
    public Empleado getEmpleado() {
        return empleado;
    }

    public void setEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
        this.empleado = empleado;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "CITA_TRATAMIENTO", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CITA_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "TRATAMIENTO_ID")},
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"CITA_ID","TRATAMIENTO_ID"}, name = "CITA_TRATAMIENTO_PK")},
    schema = "COLINASCO")
    public Set<Tratamiento> getListaTratamientos() {
        return listaTratamientos;
    }

    public void setListaTratamientos(Set<Tratamiento> listaTratamientos) {
        this.listaTratamientos = listaTratamientos;
    }
}
```

Note that the object class on the Set doesn't have a "Cita" class. That's why I didn't put it in here.

Thanks in advance if someone could help me on this.

Comment: "*is forcing me to have just one primary key on a cross-table*" - that's the **definition** of a primary key: there can only be **one**. Not even MySQL will allow you to define more then one primary key.

Comment: You can do a combine primary key too. (column1, column2) like this. That's what postgresql is not letting me do.

Comment: I dont think you can blame `postgres` I can do that in pgAdmin so the problem is with hibernate

Comment: You can absolutely define a primary key with multiple columns in Postgres: `create table foo (col1 integer, col2 integer, primary key (col1, col2));`  But I don't see any SQL in your question so I don't know what you are doing wrong. It's a problem with your obfuscation layer (aka ORM), not with Postgres. If you want an answer for Postgres, show us the `create table` statement.

Comment: If that is a join table where the two FK columns make up the primary key, then why do you have **another** unique, auto-generated ID on that table? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why do you want to use a join table for a one-to-many relationship? Are you mapping to a legacy database? And who is generating the database schema: Hibernate or you?

Answer (score 0):

From the PostgreSQL [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html):

> A table can have at most one primary key.

What you want is a composite key on two columns. The DDL will look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE cross (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  t1_id integer REFERENCES t1,
  t2_id integer REFERENCES t2,
  UNIQUE (t1_id, t2_id)
);
```

You'll have to see your ORM documents to see how to do a constraint on a composite key.

Comment: The `id` column is useless in that table definition.

Comment: Some people say to have a separate primary key, others say use the (t1_id, t2_id) composite. I don't know enough to have an opinion so I do what I was taught.

Comment: The `id` column adds no benefit here. It increases the size of the table and it adds another index that needs to be maintained. `create table foo (t1_id integer references t1, t2_id integer references t2, primary key (t1_id, t2_id))` is much more efficient and will do exactly the same thing

Comment: But your example proves that you can have a primary key **and** a unique key without problems